# You have requested a synthetic service ("request"). The DIC does not know how to construct this service

Tags: php, symfony

> You have requested a synthetic service ("request"). The DIC does not know how to construct this service.

The error received after added "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "~2.5.3" in composer.json and run update.

```
 public function listingAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $list = $em->getRepository('Avtostil\SharedBundle\Entity\Gallery')->findAll();

        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate($list, $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/* page number */, 3/* limit per page */);
        $pagination->setUsedRoute(\Avtostil\SharedBundle\Entity\Page::GALLERY_LISTING); /* QUICK AND DIRTY */

        $data = [];
        $data['galleries'] = $pagination;
        echo "<pre>";
        \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump('here');
        die();
        return $this->render('AvtostilOpenBundle:Gallery:listing.html.twig', $data);
    }
```

The dump is ok ,when I remove the error happing ?

```
in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 4094
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getRequestService() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2189
at Container->get('request', '2') in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 7503
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->synchronizeRequestService() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2125
at Container->set('request', null, 'request') in bootstrap.php.cache line 3278
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in bootstrap.php.cache line 2479
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 29
```

Comment: I think its related to the last Symfony version, I've got the same problem with 2.8.10 but not with 2.8.9. Tell me if it is the same for you.

Comment: "name": "symfony/symfony", "version": "v2.7.17",

Comment: I think its the same issue with this version, can you try with 2.7.16 ?

Comment: I pulled my version to lower and works. Thank you COil.

Comment: Check out: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19840

Comment: I wouldn't be against an accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Check out https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19840 , it's not related to your code but it's a Symfony bug that comes with both 2.7.17 and 2.8.10 versions. I think new tags should be released as the soon this bug is fixed as it will break most of the projects using the `RequestStack` service.

Edit: The issue was fixed in [2.8.11](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-2-8-11-released) and [2.7.18](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-2-7-18-released) versions.

Comment: For anybody stumbling here, This bug has now disappeared in **2.8.11**